# Google StackDriver correlating logs with parent request python 3

Tags: python, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, structured-logging

In python 2.7, the app engine sdk was doing the work in the background to nest all logs with the parent request to have a correlation in Google StackDriver.

As of the transition to python 3, it is through the usage of google cloud logging or structured logging, and from all the different references I could found, it's important to have the same trace id in the 'sub' logs for stack driver to make a match with the 'request' log.

And still as you can see below, it still appear as different logs.

For context, I even tried this on an empty django project deployed on app engine.

Got the same result, even when following the example in the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#writing_structured_logs

[image: Log StackDriver]

Trying to log to the stdout is giving the same result.

[image: Log StackDriver 2]

**Edit:**

After the initial request, all other request will be nested under the initial request when using the stdout.

But, the highest severity of the 'child' logs is not taken by the 'parent' log, therefore the filters won't pick up the actual log. See below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question!

It looks like you're logging the trace correctly, but your logName indicates that you're not using a stdout or stderr.   If you use one of these for your logs, they will correlate properly, like this:

[StackDriver Logs Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjigu.png)

You can see that the logName ends with stdout.  An stdout or stderr will correlate.  You can create this as shown here in the tutorial:

```
# Build structured log messages as an object.
global_log_fields = {}

# Add log correlation to nest all log messages
# beneath request log in Log Viewer.
trace_header = request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context')

if trace_header and PROJECT:
    trace = trace_header.split('/')
    global_log_fields['logging.googleapis.com/trace'] = (
        f"projects/{PROJECT}/traces/{trace[0]}")

# Complete a structured log entry.
entry = dict(severity='NOTICE',
             message='This is the default display field.',
             # Log viewer accesses 'component' as jsonPayload.component'.
             component='arbitrary-property',
             **global_log_fields)

print(json.dumps(entry))
```

**EDIT:**

To filter out the stdout and only see the Request logs in the stackdriver UI, you can de-select the stdout from the filter.  [Logs Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaxKk.png)

For a sample using the python client API, please see this article and attached sample Flask app.  [Combining correlated Log Lines in Google Stackdriver](https://medium.com/google-cloud/combining-correlated-log-lines-in-google-stackdriver-dd23284aeb29)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, trying it as I said is not correlating the logs for me. I did try it with a stdout and the result was the same, see the updated screenshot.

Comment: Can you try one more time?  When you re-deploy the app, this message will be correlated with the log: "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."   -- I see the same thing when I re-deploy my app. But when I reload the page, the custom message shows correlated with the request log.

Comment: You're right! It did appear inside the request! But the log appears twice: once inside the request and once in its own line. Would you know how to make the extra one disappear?

Comment: Another issue is that the 'child' log severity is not taken by the 'parent' log (request), which makes all request log with a default severity.

Comment: Added to the answer: You can easily filter out the stdout and only see the Request logs using the filter in the UI.

Comment: Regarding the severity - that's a difficult one.  B/c the request returned a 200, I'm not sure it should pick up the highest related severity?   If there is an actual error in the app, it should return a 400 or higher.   

One option you have is to create your own structured logs that replace the RequestLog.  You can put in all the same information and add your custom fields and custom severity and use this as your main source.  You can either do that with the same stdout approach you're currently taking, or you can use stackdriver logging API.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! By replacing the RequestLog, you mean logging the request myself along with other logs. That could be a solution, ideally I would have wished to have the same behavior as I had using the google appengine library in python2 (with the google appengine sdk now deprecated), unfortunately I had the same non-similar result using the stackdriver logging API

Comment: Yes - that's precisely what I meant.  I hope it works for you!  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this kind of logging structure on Google Cloud Logging Console:[image]

I was using the Django Framework. I wrote Django middleware which integrates Google Cloud Logging API.

"Trace" needs to be added to every log object which points to its parent log object.

please check [manage nesting of logs in Google Stackdriver with Django](https://djangocircle.com/how-to-manage-nesting-of-logs-in-google-stackdriver-with-django-web-apps/)

Please check [django-google-stackdriver-nested-logging](https://github.com/djangocircle/django-google-stackdriver-nested-logging) log_middleware.py source on Github.